# Can't re-install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 with Default Instance

Tags: sql-server-2008

I installed MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and I named my default instance "MSSQLSERVER". I want to uninstall that instance and start over. I used the Programs and Features control panel to completely remove MS SQL Server but when I run the installer again, the "MSSQLSERVER" instance remains. I know I can just create a new instance and call it something else but it bugs me that I didn't completely remove it.

I have searched the MS KB for information on removing MS SQL Server and everything I've found so far indicates that all I have to do is to use the Programs and Features control panel.

Can someone explain to me how to remove this instance or, if it's not possible, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a failed uninstall.  Try the following command line option to manually uninstall the instance:

At a command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER:

```
CD %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Release
```

Type the following command, and then press ENTER:

```
setup.exe /ACTION=uninstall /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER
```

Reference http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955404

If this doesn't work, let me know; there are some other ways we can try...